# Lp is complete proof understanding

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Hi I am having some trouble understanding the proof which is written in Schillings' measure theory

Statement: The spaces $L^{p} (\mu)$ are complete for $p \in [1, \infty]$.

The proof goes like this

Assume $p \in [1, \infty)$. The main difficulty is to identify the limit $u$

By the definition of cauchy sequence we find numbers

$ 1 < n(1) < n(2) < ... < n(k)$

such that

$||u_{n(k+1)} - u_{n(k)}||_{p} < 2^{-k}$

To find $u$ we turn the sequence into a series by

$u_{n(k+1)} = \sum^{k}_{i = 0} (u_{n}(i+1) - u_{n}(i)) , \ u({n_{0}}) = 0$

And as the limit $k \rightarrow \infty $ would formally be

$u :=\sum^{\infty}_{i = 0} (u_{n}(i+1) - u_{n}(i)) $

Now if we can make sense of this infinite sum. Since

$||\sum^{\infty}_{i=0} |u_{n(i+1)} - u_{n(i)}| ||_{p} \leq  \sum^{\infty}_{i=0} ||u_{n(i+1)} - u_{n(i)}||_{p} \leq ||u_{n}(1)||_{p} + \sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \frac{1}{2^{i}} (*) $

I don't see where this last inequality $(*)$ is comming from and why does that imply $u$ is absolutely convergent?

Edit:

Let us show that $u = L^p - lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} u_{n(k)}$

For this observe that by the ordinary triangle inequality and from above that

$||u - u_{n(k)}||_{p} =  || \sum^{\infty}_{i = k} (u_{n (i+1)} - u_{n(i)})||_{p}$, I don't really see where is this equality comming from?

and after some applications of the triangle inequality he gets that

$\sum^{\infty}_{i = k} || u_{n(i+1)} - u_{n(i)}||_{p} \rightarrow 0 \ as \ k \rightarrow \infty$ I am wondering how come this goes to 0 as k goes to infinity?

Comment: If someone reccomends other proofs that does not use dominated convergnce theorem nor fatous lemma that would be helpful as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first $\leq$ comes from moving the norm inside the sum. The second is this:
\begin{align*}\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty\|u_{n(i+1)}-u_{n(i)}\|_p&=|u_{n(1)}-u_{n(0)}\|_p+\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\|u_{n(i+1)}-u_{n(i)}\|_p\\
&=\|u_{n(1)}\|_p+\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\|u_{n(i+1)}-u_{n(i)}\|_p\\
&\leq \|u_{n(1)}\|_p+\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty2^{-i},
\end{align*} using that $u_{n(0)}=0$ and the choice of the subsequence.

EDIT: Let me add in a full proof. Given $(u_n)$ Cauchy in $L^p$, we can pass to a subsequence and assume that $$\|u_{n+1}-u_n\|\leq 2^{-n}.$$ Consider the sum $$u_1(x)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (u_{n+1}(x)-u_n(x)).$$ We can dominated the partial sums of this series by $g_m(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^m|u_{n+1}(x)-u_n(x)|.$ Note that $(g_m)$ satisfies that $0\leq g_1\leq g_2\leq\cdots,$ and $\|g_m\|_{L^p}\leq \sum 2^{-n}\leq 1.$ By the monotone convergence theorem, $g_m\nearrow g$ a.e. and in $L^p$ norm. This implies that $$u_1(x)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (u_{n+1}(x)-u_n(x))$$ converges a.e. to a limit, call it $u$, and applying the dominated convergence theorem yields that $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $L^p$ norm. At the end, we are using that $u_k=u_1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k-1}(u_{n+1}-u_n).$

For your new question, that's just pretty much what it means for that series to converge (which we know it does).

Comment: thank you it really makes sense. And how can I conclude absolute convergence from that ?

Comment: I think it's a little better to phrase it like this: take the sum to be finite, and define it to be a function $g_n(x).$ You can see that $0\leq g_1\leq g_2\leq\cdots,$ and via a similar argument these are all $L^p.$ By the monotone convergence theorem, they converge pointwise non-decreasingly a.e. and in $L^p$ norm, say to $g$. This implies that the series you defined $u$ by actually converges pointwise a.e. to $u$. Now, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to get convergence in $L^p$.

Comment: sorry I already accepted but had some new questions in edit..

Comment: @Chengdu I edited my post to make my comment more explicit. Does that help?

Comment: @Chengdu Also, I added in why that's true. It's just an equivalent way of saying that sequence converges.